# How to find the first row not with all cells filled by "&nbsp" with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, html-table

```
<table id="experiences" cellpadding="0" border="1" width="100%">
    <caption>table name</caption>
    <tr><th>col1</th><th>col2</th><th>col3</th><th>col4</th><th>col5</th><th>col6</th></tr>
    <tr><td>something</td><td>something</td><td>something</td><td>something</td><td>something</td><td>something</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
    <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr>
</table>
```

Like the above,the target row should be the third row from the top.

BTW, I'm not familiar with jQuery, `$().eq(0)` selects the first one, how to exclude the first one?

Will `$().ne(0)` work?

Comment: It was "& nbsp;" in <td> but somehow disapeared.

Comment: &nbsp; is used for appending space. It won't appear in the code.

Comment: You exclude the first one with :gt(0)

Comment: gt is short for great than,what about excluding the second?gt(1) will miss the 1st

Comment: $("#experiences tr").gt(0).dblclick seems wrong,double click has no response now.

Comment: Maybe you should make that another question. It's not exactly comment-material.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
function not_just_nbsp() {
    return $(this).html() !== "#nbsp;";
}

$("#experiences td").filter(not_just_nbsp).filter(":first").parent();
```

Just replace the # in nbsp with an ampersand &. Had to do it like that to make it display here on StackOverflow.

Comment: I don't understand your code,will it select out the third row as a final result?

Comment: Will this detect more than 1 whitespace in columns?

Comment: It finds all the table cells, filters out those with just a space in them, selects the last of the remaining cells, and finds the parent table row. In your example it will select the second tr on line 4.

Comment: @phoenix: If you want to rule out all table cells with only whitespace (as opposed to those with one &nbsp;) you can use a regexp in the filter function instead.

Comment: why you use $(this).html() !== " "; instead of $(this).html() !== "&nbsp;"?

Comment: For the same reason they don't show up in your example: StackOverflow won't show them. Tried fixing it now.

Comment: Oh I see..Another question,why you use .filter(":last")?Shouldn't it be .filter(":first")?

Comment: What if there is no matching row?

Comment: If there are no matching rows, that means there are no rows with anything in them, and you get an empty result.

Comment: you say "empty result",you mean its boolean value is false?

Comment: tried,seems not.then how to judge whether the result is empty or not?

Answer (score 0):

To select all rows greater than the first row, you can do:

```
$('#experiences td:gt(0)')
```

Comment: $('.yourClass').gt(0)
$('.yourClass:gt(0)') are the same ?

Comment: gah sorry... it's late here. fixed.